# How to delete an app from iTunes

Tags: itunes

Is it possible to delete an app from my Apple account; (not from my phone, from my apple account)?

Comment: Go to apps screen (View > Apps), then right click and 'delete': http://i.stack.imgur.com/CsEGm.png

Comment: I don't need to delete the apps from my Mac but from my iTunes/App Store (for iOS)

Answer (score 4):

No, once you've downloaded a paid or free app, it is registered as bought on that account.

Comment: Even if it was free?

Comment: Unfortunately so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Once bought, you cannot 'remove' it from your account. However, you can hide it from view by clicking the 'x' which appears on hovering the mouse above the app (in win/Mac). It cannot, however, be done individually from an iDevice.

Answer (score 0):

When you download an app, wether it's paid or not, it's called purchasing an app, and when you do that, the app will be "signed" with your Apple ID, after that, there's no backward step, you can't undo that. Although you can hide it as sohith said. That's it. Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to App Store click on `Purchased -> Not on this iPad/iPhone`.  Slide the app you want to hide to the left then click `Hide` (that's in red).